# Does a continuous random variable always have a cdf? A pdf?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I'm looking for the definition of a continuous random variable. Is it a r.v that has a continuous CDF? What I want to know is: is a continuous r.v defined via the CDF or PDF? i.e does there exist continuous r.v without a CDF or without a PDF?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A random variable is said to be *continuous* if its probability distribution function (AKA cumulative distribution function) is continuous. Notice the strangeness of this definition - we say a function is continuous if *some other* function is continuous!

Regarding your other questions:

- CDFs are the more fundamental object. Densities don't always exist.
- There are no random variables without a CDF. Random variables (*measurable functions*) induce (probability) measures, and the CDF is defined in terms of this measure.
- There is a continuous random variable without a density - you just need to make the CDF  weird. As mentioned, see the [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution).

Answer (score 2):

Usually, a continuous random variable refers to a rv whose distribution has a density with respect to Lebesgue measure (a PDF). However in some cases it may be meant as a rv with a continuous CDF, which is a weaker condition. To sum up:

- All random variables have a CDF.
- If it has a PDF, then its CDF is continuous.
- There are examples of distributions with continuous CDF but no PDF (see for instance Cantor dsitribution)